# Asus P9D-I IPMI mac fault

Tags: ipmi, asus

I've just bought a used Asus P9D-I Mainboard with BMC IPMI onboard. The problem is, that I cannot access the IPMI WebConsole because the mac address in the bios is completely zeroed (00-00-00-00-00) I tried to update the BMC to the newest firmware (2.01) an tried to reset the mac address with a live debian and ipmitool. But the address is still zeroed. The board has a shared ipmi nic, not a dedicated one. I also dont know the "real" mac address of the ipmi chipset.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking in the bios and configuring a new mac there? the mac just needs to be unique within the collision domain it exists within, not unique in the world.